# Unable to install pip modules or do anything related to pip caches

Tags: python, caching, pip

***I uses PyCharm's terminal for the action below.***

I was unable to install packages using pip. If I tried to install, it raises a error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\~\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\~\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 68, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "C:\Users\~\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 114, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\~\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cache import WheelCache
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.cache'
```

Looking at the error, I found it's related to "caches", And I wrote a program which deletes all files which contains "cache" in it's name a few days ago since my computer is full of cache before.

My question is: Is it possible to add back the pip cache file back?
Looking forward to replys and answers.

Edit: Errors returned by using "pip install":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\terence\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 31, in <module>
    sys.exit(_main())
  File "C:\Users\terence\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 68, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "C:\Users\terence\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 114, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\terence\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\uninstall.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import SessionCommandMixin, warn_if_run_as_root
  File "C:\Users\terence\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cache import WheelCache
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.cache'
```

Comment: It is possible to add back the pip cache file, but it may not always be necessary or the best solution. The pip cache is a directory on your system where pip stores the packages it has downloaded from the internet, so that it doesn't have to download them again the next time you need to install the same package.

If the cache file has been deleted or become corrupted, you can try restoring it by running the following command:

pip install --download-cache path/to/directory

Where "path/to/directory" is the location where you want to store the cache.

Comment: Somehow, I was unable to do any pip install action on PyCharm terminal. However, I can do pip install on cmd. Weird to me. I'm not sure PyCharm terminal can do pip install action. If not, I'll mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.cache'" typically indicates that there is an issue with the version of pip that you have installed on your system. This error message occurs when the module 'pip._internal.cache' is not found in the version of pip that you are using.

To fix this error, you can try upgrading pip to the latest version by running the command:

> pip install --upgrade pip

If the issue persists, you can try uninstalling and reinstalling pip using the command:

> python -m pip uninstall pip

And then

> python -m pip install pip

Alternatively, you can try installing the package using the following command:

> python -m pip install package_name

It's also possible that you have multiple versions of python installed on your system, and the one you're using doesn't have pip package. In this case, you can try running the above command with the python version that has pip installed.

It's also a good practice to use virtual environments to keep the dependencies and packages isolated.

Please let me know if there's anything else I can help with.

Comment: I've tried it, but everything related to "pip install" has been broken to me.
It returns the same error to me.

Comment: Please share the error statement of broken pip installation

Comment: Attached on the question.

Comment: Sorry for late response.The "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.cache'" error can occur when using an older version of pip. This error message indicates that the 'pip._internal.cache' module is not found.  try: python -m pip install --upgrade pip   and python -m ensurepip --upgrade

Comment: Late response. I tried it on cmd, but it give a message said that "No such option: -m"

Answer (score 0):

As you python environment is broken, I'd recommend you to **reinstall pip**.

If that doesn't work, just reinstall python.

Also, better don't delete all files with a specific name-pattern.
You (as you see) just break programms with it.
Better delete all files in you **temp** folder (%temp% in windows)

Comment: How to reinstall pip? I tried "pip install pip --force-reinstall" before but it used "pip install"  
and it broke.

Comment: I designed the program to delete cache of app in Appdata, like Google Chrome's `code cache` folder.

Comment: I've just upgrade python 3.9 to python 3.10. Somehow it works in cmd. Thanks! However I still cannot do it in pycharm terminal.

Comment: I think you'll need to reinstall the venv in pycharm, and delete the old one. Should bt possible in the settings